# printer spool's issue with HP Deskjet F4200

Tags: apache-flex, printing, flex4, printers

I m using printer functionality in my project with HP Deskjet F4200 printer series.

In that printer functionality i m facing one issue that when i am printing the particular page, it is printing perfectly but the printer spoofy window shows like 3/1 and prints single page.

The working fine when i print as PDF. This issue only comes when i try to print the page directly. i dont know this is printer problem or my coding problem.

Comment: Did you check it with other printers???

Comment: What do you mean by print the page directly?  Exactly how do you print?